# Why is this ng-show directive not working in a template?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write a directive that will do a simple in-place edit for an element. This is my code so far:

```
directive('clickEdit', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  template: '<span ng-show="inEdit"><input ng-model="editModel"/></span>' +
            '<span ng-show="!inEdit" ng-click="edit()">{{ editModel }}</span>',
  scope: {
    editModel: "=",
    inEdit: "@"
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.inEdit = false;
    var savedValue = scope.editModel;
    var input = element.find('input');

    input.bind('keyup', function(e) {
      if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
        scope.save();
      } else if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) {
        scope.cancel();
      }
    });

    scope.edit = function() {
      scope.inEdit = true;
      setTimeout(function(){
        input[0].focus();
        input[0].select();
      }, 0);
    };

    scope.save = function() {
      scope.inEdit = false;
    };

    scope.cancel = function() {
      scope.inEdit = false;
      scope.editModel = savedValue;
    };
  }
}
})
```

The scope.edit function sets inEdit to true, and that works well - it hides the text and shows the input tag. However, the scope.save function, which sets scope.inEdit to false does not work at all. It does not hide the input tag and show the text.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `scope.save()` from a event handler reacting to the `keyup` event. However this event handler is not called by/through the AngularJS framework. AngularJS will only scan for changes of the model if it believes that changes might have occured in order to lessen the workload (AngularJS as of now does dirty-checking with is computational intensive).

Therefore you must make use of the `scope.$apply` feature to make AngularJS aware that you are doing changes to the scope. Change the `scope.save` function to this and it shall work:

```
scope.save = function(){
  scope.$apply(function(){
    scope.inEdit = false;
  });
});
```

Also it appears that there is actually no need to bind this `save` function to a scope variable. So you might want to instead define a "normal" function or just integrate the code into your event handler.